# Join query with foreach in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to learn Laravel, so I apologize if my question is simple.
 I have 2 table (table1, table2) like this:
table1:

```
ID       date       time
1          1          1
2          4          2
3          5          3
```

table2:

```
ID       V        R
1        123       T
1        12        F
1        43        F
2        32        T
2        23        T
3        43        F
```

because I have 3 type of IDs (which could be more or less) I want to divide table2 into 3 tables using table1. like this: 
table2_1: for ID:1

```
V       R
123     T
12      F
43      F
```

table2_2: for ID:2

```
V       R
23       T
23       T
```

table2_3: for ID:3

```
V       R
43       F
```

I think I need somthing like this:

```
@foreach ($table1 as $t)
      <table class="table">
         {!! $t -> ID!!}
        <thead>
        <tr>

            <th scope="col">R</th>
            <th scope="col">V</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <!---Query result ---->

        </tbody>

 @endforeach
```

which in Query result I need a to select V and R from joining table1 and table2.
but I don'n know the exact code. 
Any Idea how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not even need to involve `table1` here.  Just query `table2` with an `ORDER BY` clause, and then iterate the result set, turning out new HTML tables for each new `ID` value:

```
$result = DB::table('table2')
            ->orderBy('ID')
            ->get();

$prev_id = NULL;

foreach($result as $row) {
    $curr_id = $row->ID;
    if ($prev_id != NULL && $curr_id != $prev_id) {
        echo "</table>";
    }
    if ($prev_id == NULL || $curr_id != $prev_id) {
        $prev_id = $curr_id;
        echo "<table class=\"table\" colspan=\"2\">";
        echo "<tr><th scope=\"col\">V</th><th scope=\"col\">R</th></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row->V . "</td><td>" . $row->R . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works but it shows V and R for every row and does not show ID for each table. anyway I think I found another way to do this without Query, but I have a little problem comparing these 2 thing. "@if(({!! $s['ID_port'] !!})==({!! $t -> ID_port!!}))" Do you know how can I compare them. one of them is the result of the get() and one of them is from a table.

Comment: @afsane Please try my updated code.  I left something out.  Realize that I can't easily do any testing here.

Comment: It totally works but it is in controller.php (right?) because of this, it does not look like my other table (they are in show.blade.php). any idea how can I pass it to my HTML code and show it from there?

Comment: I have zero knowledge of Blade, which AFAIK is the name of a good 90s Wesley Snipes vampire movie.  See if you can adapt my PHP code.  I literally have a single variable for state (`$prev_id`), so if you can incorporate that, the rest should just work.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Again Thank you so much.